# RemoteView get assigned Resource

Tags: android, android-remoteview

Is there a way to get the assigned "ImageViewResource" or Bitmap of a RemoteView? I can successfully set the resource invoking remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap or remoteViews.setImageViewResource.

Background info: I want to set a default image in a try/catch only if there is no image set (the old one can be shown).